# Show category name above category posts

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I'm trying to get the category name to show above posts. I'm customizing bones and am a little stuck.

Here's the code that has my posts displaying, and I have each in a category in the wp admin. I'm just not sure how to get the category to display above the appropriate posts.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance!!

```
<?php 
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom_type', 'posts_per_page' => 100 );
      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
      ?>
      <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
      <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <div class="entry-content">
      <?php the_content(); ?> 
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
      <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing a custom loop (as opposed to "The loop"), hence you'll need to pass the id of the post to `get_the_category`. However, judging by the docs, it seems that WP_Query->the_post() sets the global post.

So, if  this does not work:

```
<h2><?php echo get_the_category() ?></h2>
```

You would do:

```
$postsQuery = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $postQuery->get_posts(); 
foreach ( $posts as $i => $e ) {
   $category = get_the_category($e->ID);
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: There is a culture of copy-paste solutions over at wp forums. That does not apply here. I use "that code" and I am fairly confident in that it has some value as a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I could not post in comments, but if above answer is working for you as you posted in comments but having issue with getting category as it give array due to many categories of a post, so you need to fetch first category from the array. Use below code snippet:

```
if ( ! empty( $category ) ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category[0]->name ) . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like `<?php the_category();?>`. This will returns the categories name with link. Hope this help you!